# Git Repository on External HDD and on PC

Tags: git

I have an Unreal Engine project that I want to keep a repository for on an external HDD but I don't want to work on it from the HDD, just upload changes to the project if that makes sense. I will have a repository on the PC too

Comment: A Git repository is not a big problem and should work out-of-the-box. What is the problem you are facing? I would recommend to make the repo on the external HDD a "bare" repository.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know what to look for but I figured it out from your suggestion.